# MySQL server has gone away due to error CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, xampp

XAMPP MySQL server crashed and shows an Error message like SQL query: `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';`

I have tried searched in Apache Friends [Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewforum.php?f=16), I am new to XAMPP i  am facing this problem, So. Where should i need to change / run the query.

[image]

File « D:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

```
## UTF 8 Settings
init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Un-comment PHP's default character set `default_charset = "UTF-8"` in `D:\xampp\php\php.ini` file. it is working fine.

```
; PHP's built-in default is text/html
; http://php.net/default-mimetype
default_mimetype = "text/html"

; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Made some changes in `D:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` file

```
## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

Answer (score 0):

First stop Xammp server
Then add in my.ini file

```
character_set_database=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
```

and then start

FOR php you should edit

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

in htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Non-problem.

`ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away` is not caused by any `SET`, it is caused by a timeout.  You had left the connection idle too long.  It probably reconnected and all was well.

For example (my connection had not been touched in about 15 hours, as can bee seen by the prompt):

```
18:57:12 wamp [try] 46> SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1935
Current database: try

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

09:41:29 wamp [try] 47> SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```